# How can I share my desktop audio with Lync?

Tags: lync

In a Lync desktop (or Application) sharing session, is there any way to share the audio too? A simple example would be Winamp. If I share Winamp, can the people I share the application with hear it? It appears not, but I have my fingers crossed that someone here can save the day.

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question: http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm

Comment: you can answer your own question in a couple of days, be sure to do so if you've found an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to check out http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm, they have some good advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

We have run into this problem trying to share training videos from the internet with our Lync meeting attendees but following the instructions at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/play-a-video-in-a-lync-meeting-103ba3eb-5c08-4cc9-a797-44dd39d3a96f seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.